# ionic app url found localhost instead file folder

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native, ionic-view

After generating Android build and inspect within Google chrome.

The url in app should be file:///android_asset/www/index.html (Image2)

But always getting localhost.

Why its showing localhost:8080 …?? (image1)

The url in app should be file:///android_asset/www/index.html
But its running in localhost://8080

[image: Displaying Image 2]

[image: Displaying Image 1]

Answer (score 0):

yes, Ionic always getting node(npm) as a localhost server

Comment: It's the case when we build .apk and debug in chrome using Remote Devices. There is should run from file:///android_asset/www  and NOT localhost:8080